# How to combine information of two tables using a third table?

Tags: postgresql

I have to reference information of a table using the PK from another table. For that I have to see if the information matches in a third table.

To better explain, I show you the screenshots the *SELECT* from the tables I need to use or change.

In the next two screenshot of tables, I have an Address table that contains information about differentes addresses and an "addressid" PK. The next table, is a Company table that provides information about differentes companies. These companies need to have two FKs to the Address table in the two different columns that are empty.

[image: Address Table]
[image: Company Table]

So, I have a table with a lot of mixed information, including the addresses combined with the companies.

Using this "import" tables, I have to set the empty FK on Company table related to the PKs of Address table.

[image: Import table part 1]
[image: Import table part 2]

I have tried doing an UPDATE function but I don't really know how to write the conditions to use this "import" table to relate the other two tables.

Thanks on advance.

In the IMPORT table I have all the info in Company table and Address table, but mixed, with other unused information. So, I have for each row in Company, look at the Company name, search it on the import table, look in the same row what is the address, search it on the Address table and put the correspondent PK on the Company table... Example: COMPANY - Google IMPORT - Google California ADDRESS - Californa id1 Go to COMPANY - Google (add id1 on column address)... Sorry if I explain it not so good.

Comment: MySQL is not PostgreSQL. Please use correct tags.

Comment: Can you provide information on how exactly each of the id fields in the `company` table should be resolved to a row in the `address` table?

Comment: @404 In the IMPORT table I have all the info in Company table and Address table, but mixed, with other unused information. So, I have for each row in Company, look at the Company name, search it on the import table, look in the same row what is the address, search it on the Address table and put the correspondent PK on the Company table...
Example:
COMPANY - Google
IMPORT - Google California
ADDRESS - Californa id1

Go to COMPANY - Google (add id1 on column address)...

Sorry if I explain it not so good.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for the shipping address:

```
update company c
set ordership_address = (select addressid 
                           from address a
                             inner join import i 
                                     on a.addressname = i.ordershipadress
                                        and a.postalcode = i.ordershippostalcode
                                     -- and other criteria ?
                          where i.companyname = c.companyname)
```

Don't know how your address.cityid maps to something so leave that one for you.